# What’s the difference between Xcode, Objective-C and Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

This question pops up quite often here, even if just implicitly when users mistag their iOS questions. So, what’s the difference between Xcode, Objective-C and Cocoa?

Comment: It's the difference between a pen, English, and a public library.

Comment: @Catfish_Man It was really really helpful man, not...specially for anyone starting to dive into iOS development

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Objective-C is a programming language. It could be said that it’s just a description of what valid Objective-C programs look like and what they mean. If you have a source code listing written in Objective-C, you need an interpreter or a compiler to put the listing to work. Languages like Objective-C are usually compiled, so most people use a compiler (like [LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)). Objective-C is almost exclusively used to develop for iOS and OS X, but there are other uses, too – as an example, some people write Objective-C for Linux.

You can use a text editor to write the sources and a compiler to turn them into an actual programs, but with modern technologies there’s much more to take care of, so that there is another program to make your job easier. These are called Integrated Development Environments, or IDEs. An IDE offers you a convenient way to edit the sources, compile them, debug the resulting programs, read the documentation, and many other things. Xcode is one such IDE. An important observation here is that Xcode does not compile your sources itself, it just calls the standalone compiler (LLVM). And Xcode is not the only IDE you can use to develop Objective-C apps – there’s [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/), for example.

Writing iOS or OS X apps from scratch each time would be very time-consuming. That’s why Apple provides the developers with a good set of libraries. The libraries are simply a huge amount of source code written by Apple, and this source code takes care of most things that apps have in common. These libraries are called Cocoa.

Now, if you can’t figure out how to extend a class, you are most probably talking about Objective-C. It doesn’t have anything to do with Xcode or Cocoa, you could be very well writing some [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/) code for Linux using Vim as an IDE and GCC as a compiler. On the other hand, if your Xcode build process fails because of some mysterious setting, or if you’re trying to build a static library in Xcode, that’s clearly an Xcode issue. And if you can’t figure out how to use some NSObject facility or the NSFileManager class, that’s Cocoa. (But it doesn’t have to be Xcode-related, as you could use AppCode or TextMate as your IDE!)

---

[Originally available on my blog](http://blog.zmotula.cz/post/31915106673/the-difference-between-xcode-objective-c-and-cocoa). Feel free to link to the blog post or this question when retagging or explaining the difference.

Comment: good post, but I gotta ask, based on this statement..."These libraries are called Cocoa"...a question arises, what's the difference between the "Foundation" and "Cocoa" framework? Does Cocoa sit on top off the Foundation framework?

Comment: Yes, Cocoa could be said to be the topmost library layer sitting atop the Foundation (see http://goo.gl/H22M8g). In other words, the description is a bit imprecise in this point – Cocoa is just a part of the software stack offered by Apple for writing software.

Comment: Very nice and explanatory answer.. and really helped me knowing the difference.  But here comes another question :) by Cocoa libraries; is it the same as APIs ?

Answer (score 8):

Xcode is the integrated development environment (IDE)—the application—that developers use to write software for iOS and/or OS X. It includes the editor, the build system (determining what to build to produce the desired target), and quite a few other things.

Objective-C is the main language that developers write such software in. They may write bits of it in pure C, use C++ or combine it with Objective-C (producing Objective-C++), or write some or all of the program in another language entirely, such as MacRuby, Java (with j2objc), or C# (with MonoTouch).

Xcode includes the Clang compiler, which turns code written in Objective-C, C, and a few other languages into executable code. Most error messages come from Clang, and Xcode relies heavily on it for search indexing, syntax highlighting, and name completion of Objective-C code.

Cocoa and Cocoa Touch are application frameworks. Each one is a suite of many individual frameworks (libraries stored in folders named blahblah.framework), such as:

- Foundation (both): General object-oriented utilities, including NSString, NSURL, NSFileManager, etc.

  - Core Foundation (both): Mostly the same thing, but different, mainly in having a C-based API rather than Objective-C
- Application Kit (Mac): Application and windowing framework
- UIKit (iOS): Application and windowing framework
- Core Graphics (both): Drawing
- Core Animation (both): Sprite-management and animation framework

(and many, many more where they came from, especially on the Mac)

So:

- You can use a framework besides Cocoa or Cocoa Touch, but you'll have to have *some* Cocoa/Cocoa Touch code, at some level, in order for your application to talk to the system, receive events, draw, etc. Frameworks that specifically target Mac and/or iOS will include the relevant wrappers for you, at varying levels of quality.
- You can use a language besides Objective-C, but you'll have lots of syntactic awkwardness, as most of Cocoa and Cocoa Touch are designed for Objective-C's unique syntactic features (particularly selectors).
- You can use an editor besides Xcode, and you can even use a build system besides Xcode (such as make), but Apple's App Stores expect apps built a particular way (especially with regard to code signing), so unless you're not targeting the App Stores, any other build system has to replicate what Xcode does or risk its users getting rejections.

Answer (score 1):

A clear mistake is failing to differentiate Xcode from everything else. Xcode is the tool you are using to program in - to edit code, run code, etc. So if you are having trouble with the *tool* (e.g., the window doesn't show you your code properly, or you're having trouble drawing your interface, etc.), that's an Xcode problem.

If you don't understand why your *code doesn't work*, you're probably having an Objective-C problem or a Cocoa problem. But you won't necessarily know which.

- It's an Objective-C problem if the root of your trouble is that you don't know how the language works (e.g. you don't know what the asterisk is for, or that declaration is not instantiation, or that messages to nil do not error out but don't do anything either).
- It's a Cocoa problem if you don't grasp the delegate architecture or how a view controller works.

But my experience of the way people pose questions is that you may be ignorant of *which* of these you are ignorant of. I don't mean you personally, I mean all of us. This can make it difficult to pose the question properly because you don't know what exactly it is that you don't know — if you did, you'd know it and you probably wouldn't be having a problem (you'd be fixing the problem and on to the next thing).