# Xcode 5 use different image depending on if using iOS 7 or lower

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there a clever way now with Xcode 5 to load different images in your app depending whether it is iOS7 or not?

the best solution i can come up with is having "_7" appended on the end of the images needed for iOS7 and then when using images in the app i can go:

```
NSString *OSSuffix = OSVersion == 7 ? @"_7" : @""; //would be define globally, also pseudo syntax
[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageName%@", OSSuffix]]; //can make a macro for this probably
```

but is there a better more 'built in' way of doing this with the new asset catalog or something?

Comment: The asset catalog has nothing to do with this.  It is unusual to want new images simply because of a new version of an OS, so this functionality is something you will need to implement yourself.

Comment: One solution is to have all your images delivered through an imageProvider, then at least you wouldn't need to copy that code everywhere. Also: if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)

Comment: @borrrden when you have custom buttons and stuff in your app that are not flat like the rest of iOS 7, it looks kind of odd, and vice versa for iOS 6. im sure a lot of current apps will run into this kind of problem

Comment: Sorry, but what does this have to do with Xcode?

Comment: @dandan78 if you read the question, im asking if there is new functionality in xcode 5 to support this, since it seems to me something that a lot of current apps would want/need

Comment: You probably mean the iOS 7 SDK, but okay. Xcode is just an IDE...

Comment: Related question: [What’s the difference between Xcode, Objective-C and Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509859/whats-the-difference-between-xcode-objective-c-and-cocoa)

Comment: i really do mean xcode 5, and not the sdk, i do know the difference. im not really looking for a code based solution here (unless something easier than i suggested), which would be to do with the sdk. but enough debate about semantics, lets keep the comments on topic here

Comment: So, to make things clear, are you looking for the functionality in the Interface Builder that’s now a part of Xcode?

Comment: I understand that it is a problem, but it is not really Apple's problem.  That's the point.  If you used all custom buttons then it will still look just as nice (We aren't upgrading all of our buttons and such for iOS 7).  So this feature would be considered bloat by many.

Answer (score 2):

[I was wondering about a similar use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916656/apart-from-2x-what-other-tags-are-supported-by-uiimage), loading the 568-pixels-high images automatically based on the device type. Since the functionality was not offered, I came up with a patch to `UIImage`, [there’s a sample project here on GitHub](https://github.com/zoul/iOS-Image-Loader):

```
+ (void) load
{
    if  (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        // Running on iPad, nothing to change.
        return;
    }

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    BOOL tallDevice = (screenBounds.size.height > 480);
    if (!tallDevice) {
        // Running on a 320✕480 device, nothing to change.
        return;
    }

    method_exchangeImplementations(
        class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(imageNamed:)),
        class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(imageNamedH568:))
    );
}

// Note that calling +imageNamedH568: here is not a recursive call,
// since we have exchanged the method implementations for +imageNamed:
// and +imageNamedH568: above.
+ (UIImage*) imageNamedH568: (NSString*) imageName
{
    NSString *tallImageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-568h@2x"];
    NSString *tallImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:tallImageName ofType:@"png"];
    if (tallImagePath != nil) {
        // Tall image found, let’s use it. We just have to pass the
        // image name without the @2x suffix to get the correct scale.
        imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-568h"];
    }
    return [UIImage imageNamedH568:imageName];
}
```

You could use the same trick to automatically load iOS 7 resources based on some custom name tag. Also the same caveat applies: the `UIImage` trick uses method swizzling and may be too much magic to have in production. Your call.

Comment: Really nice solution that perfectly demonstrates the use of swizzling.